# Angular2, ASP.NET 5 project setup. "Type expected" error on di.d.ts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, angular

I am trying to get familiar with Angular2, TypeScript and ASP.NET 5. I am not very familiar with any of them so am following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zkesm9CUP_o&feature=youtu.be

My problem is that once I try to import from 'angular2/angular2' I am getting a build error in one of the Angular2 Typescript files.

So here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here is tsconfig.json

[image]

Here is gulpfile.js

[image]

and app.ts just contains the following:

```
import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
```

When I try to build, I get an error in di.d.ts. this is located in src\node_modules\angular2\src\core\metadata\di.d.ts

This is the error:

Error   TS1110
Build: Type expected.

This is the line that the error refers to:

[image]

Any ideas why I'm getting this?

Comment: Upgrade your TypeScript to 1.7.3

Comment: I already have version 1.7.3

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5778

Comment: Hmmm, so if I have Version 1.7.3 (which is what i'm told when I run tsc -v on the package manager console) why is it not recognising the `this` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's an error in the type definition file. Change

```
token: this;
```

to

```
token: AttributeMetadata;
```

and it should compile.

**EDIT**:
This is indeed a feature, as @Eric Martinez commented, called "Polymorphic *this* Typing". Updating to TypeScript 1.7+ fixes the issue.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature (no, not a joke) introduced in [TypeScript 1.7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/11/30/announcing-typescript-1-7.aspx)